# Twice belongs_to maps back to the same table 'User'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :commenter, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "commenter_user_id"
   belongs_to :student, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "student_user_id"
```

They both belong to User.

I get it if this is done once because it helps to make it more clearer or whatnot ...

But why twice to map it back to the same table?!?!?

So, as result Comment columns are this:

```
  [0] "id",
  [1] "comment",
  [2] "student_user_id",
  [3] "commenter_user_id",
  [4] "created_at",
  [5] "updated_at",
  [6] "partnership_id"
```

Please excuse this if it seems same as my previous question. For me, it's not. Or maybe I didn't get it clearly enough. Hm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Comment` can be  posted by a `Commentator` who is a `User` and a `Comment` can also be posted by a `Student` who is also a `User` So it is best to define like your way

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :commenter, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "commenter_user_id"
   belongs_to :student, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "student_user_id"
```

rather than just defining like this

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :commenter
   belongs_to :student
```

Comment: is it also a way to prevent creation of additional specific tables such as `commenter` & `student`?

Comment: No!`commenter` and `student` tables should be created for this to work.

Comment: but there are no `student` and `commenter` tables.

Comment: i mean, they both map back to User, you know? So, they both reference that table. I thought what your answer explained was that user as student could make a comment, or as a commenter, but it still comes back to user. (hope this makes sense).

Comment: @user2730725 yeah! you are right.I mean the `commenter` & `student` tables require to store their data